# Dynamically Extend VueJs Component based on prop

Tags: vuejs2, jsx, vue-chartjs

Firstly I want to say this question isn't set in stone as I am very willing to try other suggestions being the fact I may have completely missed a suitable method.

I am using Vue-ChartJs within JSX but want to get to a point where at the beginning of an app I don't have to extend every chart component i need e.g.:

```
    // Line bar component.
Vue.component('line-chart', {
    extends: VueChartJs.Line,

    props: ['data', 'options'],

    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
    }
});
```

Instead, I want to dynamically extend the component based on, maybe, a prop that will determine what to extend by:

```
const getChart = (type) => {
    if (type === 'bar') {
        return VueChartJs.Bar;
    };
};

Vue.component('chart', {
    props: ['data', 'options', 'type'],
    extends: () => {
        getChart(this.type)
    },
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
    }
})
```

This method doesn't work at present because in extends: it returns an error of t is undefined which "this" is not being set.

Are there any suggestions as to a possible solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the `type` property effectively decides which component to use. The built in property `is` is more suitable for this job. Note that here I am still registering all components, but using a util function makes the code very short and easy.

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <!-- think of :is like the :type property in your example, it serves the same purpose -- deciding which component to use -->
        <component :is="chartTypeLine" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions"></component>
        <component :is="chartTypeBar" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions"></component>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script>
<script>

    const getChart = (type) => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'line-chart':
                return VueChartJs.Line;
            case 'bar-chart':
                return VueChartJs.Bar;
            default:
                throw new Error("wrong chart type");
        }
    };

    const chartTypes = ['line-chart', 'bar-chart'];

    //this makes registering all those components easier.
    chartTypes.forEach(type => {
        Vue.component(type, {
            extends: getChart(type),
            props: ['data', 'options'],
            mounted () {
                this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
            }
        })
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            chartData: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                        data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
                    }
                ]
            },
            chartOptions: {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false},
            chartTypeLine: 'line-chart',
            chartTypeBar: 'bar-chart'
        }
    })
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBxRpP

Answer (score 1):

As well as the previous answer, I also discovered another way to do it this morning. It instantiates each chart type via an object using the same foreach loop when the JSX file is first run, this registers them all in the scope ready to be used.

```
const chartNames = [
    {
        name: 'line-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Line
    }, {
        name: 'bar-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Bar
    },
    {
        name: 'horizontal-bar-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.HorizontalBar
    },
    {
        name: 'doughnut-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Doughnut
    },
    {
        name: 'pie-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Pie
    },
    {
        name: 'radar-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Radar
    },
    {
        name: 'polar-area-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.PolarArea
    },
    {
        name: 'bubble-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Bubble
    },
    {
        name: 'scatter-chart',
        type: VueChartJs.Scatter
    }];
const registerCharts = (chartNames) => {
    chartNames.forEach((chartName) => {
        Vue.component(chartName.name, {
            extends: chartName.type,
            mixins: [VueChartJs.mixins.reactiveProp],
            props: {
                options: Object
            },
            methods: {
                // Used in the alternate render version, this updates the chart in question.
                update() {
                    this.$data._chart.update()
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
            }
        });
    })
};
registerCharts(chartNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this one

Chart.js

```
import VueChartJs from 'vue-chartjs'
import Vue from 'vue'

const getChart = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'LineChart':
      return VueChartJs.Line
    case 'BarChart':
      return VueChartJs.Bar
    case 'PieChart':
      return VueChartJs.Pie
    default:
      throw new Error('wrong chart type')
  }
}

// generate component via fun
// it mean that you will generate as many components as you need

export default (type) => {
  return Vue.component(type, {
    extends: getChart(type),
    name: type,
    props: ['data', 'options'],
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
    }
  })
}
```

index.vue

```
<template> 
..
        <PieChart
          :data="testData"
          :options="options"
        />
..
</template>

<script>
import Chart from '~/components/UI/Chart/index'
..
export default {
  components: {
    PieChart: Chart('PieChart')
  }

}
</script>
```